# Where can i find the lightdm folders and and images

Tags: 11.10, lightdm

I am trying to build my own greeter for Ubuntu 11.10 and amd looking for all the folders that are being used by lightdm. So far i have located the .conf files and the unity-greeter folder but it seems that i haven't located all the files/folders

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
dpkg -L lightdm
```

lists you all the files installed by the `lightdm` package.

If you want to have a look at the source code of lightdm use

```
apt-get source lightdm
```