# How do I move the dialog in the login screen?

Tags: 11.10, lightdm

I have a quite wide monitor and it's quite annoying to see the login dialog in the login screen on the far left side of my screen. I literally have to turn my head around to look at it!

Is there a way to center the login dialog?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, the login dialog is designed to be in that location and this is not configurable.

However it would be possible for people to make their own greeter that is more configurable for things like this:

- [How do I set my own (HTML) theme in LightDM?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/69151/how-do-i-set-my-own-html-theme-in-lightdm)
- [Where can i find the lightdm folders and and images](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61938/where-can-i-find-the-lightdm-folders-and-and-images)

Answer (score 2):

If you use lightdm-gtk-greeter instead of the default unity-greeter you can specify the login window position since version 1.7.0:
Edit your greeter conf file (/etc/lightdm/lightdm-gtk-greeter.conf) and set the position:

```
# 960px from the left and 25% from the top
position=960 25%

# or 25% from the right and 400px from the bottom
position=-25% -400
```

Comment: Hi Nicolas, is this a new feature with lightdm? (I'm not in Ubuntu yet to test it, but remind me to get back to this answer!

Comment: This new feature came with the version 1.7.0 of LightDM in december 2013. (http://smdavis.us/2013/12/28/lightdm-gtk-greeter-1-7-0-released/)

Comment: This is a feature of lightdm-gtk-greeter not unity-greeter which is the default greeter used in Ubuntu. LightDM itself does not provide a greeter.